# Terminator custom command inside ssh

Tags: 14.04, command-line, ssh, terminator

Referring to many Q&A before, I was successfully able to execute multiple custom commands on a terminator launch.

Right now this is my workflow:

1. Launch terminator
2. Step 1 launches a custom layout with remote session. (success)
3. I want to execute a command inside the remote session on launch. (need help)

Is there any way to add a custom command like `ssh remotehost; ls`  ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking if you can run multiple commands in a single ssh session, the answer is yes.  Try the following:

```
ssh user@host '(w; df -h)'
```

This should output both the results of the w command on the remote host, as well as the df -h output on the remote host.

Hope this helps.